# Class BrowserModule is not an Angular module

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, angular-cli, angular-module

When I am creating a new angular project, it gives me error at imports in the 'app.module.ts' file.

[image: The IDE error description screenshot here]

Code:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from "@angular/platform-browser";

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,    //error here
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This has happened for the first time, can someone please suggest what is to be done.

Comment: Is the error only visible in the IDE or does it pop up when you try to compile the project?

Comment: tried npm install? Maybe also delete your node_modules folder before, to do a complete re-install

Comment: And please provide some more details: What's the exact error? What does it say? Where and when does it pop up?

Comment: @PhilippMeissner yes visible only in the IDE. I am able to compile and run the program.

Comment: @AndreasRainer I have edited the question and attached the IDE error screenshot along with the description. And I have already tried re-installing.

Comment: Not really a solution per se, but you may not experience this problem if you try in VS Code

Comment: what IDEA and Angular versions do you work with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same issue.
Just try to update everything. I updated WebStorm to a higher version and used 'ng update' to upgrade the project. Now the error is gone.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This helped in my case it was a minor update. I normally try to avoid package updates when trying to get a skeleton app to run again. This was good advice and the minor update helped. thanks.